# Mount point for multiple ext4 partition

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning, mount, ext4

I can't find any related question and answer that will satisfy me on my quest. All I see that people telling to create a ext partition with mount point `'/'` and a swap space. But I want to create multiple(3) ext partitions. I just want to keep them separately so that I can access them individually.

I used ext4 as partitioning format and provide mount point `'/'` to one partition and left other partitions mount point without selecting anything. During next step it provide a warning message for those partitions.

After installation now I can see them individually. Still I don't put any data on those partitions. I am just thinking is it a bad idea not to provide any mount point? And for multiple ext4 partitions is it OK? Is there any performance problem may occur on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reason to give them permanent mount points unless you want to.

When you feel like using one of them, you can just mount it /mnt or anywhere else you wish:

From the command line:

```
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
```

(assuming /dev/sda4 was the partition you wanted to mount). Or you could mount them someplace else like /home/yourusername/somedirectoryyoumade